# A problem about normal subgroup of a generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

**Problem** A finite group $G$ has exactly two subgroups of order $n$, denoted as $H$ and $K$ (*i.e.*, apart from $H$ and $K$, there are no subgroups of $G$ of order $n$ anymore). Suppose $G$ is generated by $H$ and $K$. Prove that $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

**Definition**(normal subgroup) Suppose that $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. We call $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ if $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$.

I have figured out that for a specific $g\in G$, $gHg^{−1}$ is a subgroup of order $n$, which implies either $gHg^{−1}=H$ or $gHg^{−1}=K$. Now what I need to do is to rule out the possibility of $gHg^{−1}=K$ for any $g\in G$ and this is the point puzzling me... I have no idea how to use "$G$ is generated by $H$ and $K$".

A similar and trivial proposition is shown as follows:

**Proposition** A finite group $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $n$, denoted as $H$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What definition of a normal subgroup are you using? What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? What similar problems have you encountered so far? What's the first thing you don't understand about the problem? Answering questions such as these with an [edit] to your question body will prevent downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: @Shaun, thank you very much for your help! This is the very first time I write a post here^_^

Comment: You're welcome, @atlantic0cean :)

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly stated Problem'?  Because "Problem' A finite group G has [...] subgroup [...], denoted [...] H. Prove that H is a subgroup of G." is immediate, as written.

Comment: @eric Yes, it is trivial... maybe I should call it a trivial proposition instead of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h\in H$, suppose that $hKh^{-1}$ is not $K$, this implies that $hKh^{-1}=H$, we also have $hHh^{-1}=H$. Write $f_h(x)=hxh^{-1}$. Let $k\in K$ we have $f_h(k)=f_h(h'), h'\in H$ implies that $hkh^{-1}=hh'h^{-1}$ implies that $k=h'\in H, K\subset H$. Contradiction, this implies that $K$ is normal since $H$ and $K$ generates $G$.

Comment: I think this works! Thank you very much!